# Whats the best way to use a git repo for collaborators?

Tags: git

In general, whats the best way to use a repo for collaborators? Should we both just push and pull from the master repo or would we have a branch for each collaborator and then merge when appropriate?

Apologies if this is a stupid/basic question; git noob here ;-)Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your Project , i would recommend you do branches for each group on the project

Comment: Always try to summarize your question in the title. "General git question" doesn't tell anybody anything more than the tags.

Comment: Man, I wish I could get reputation for the answer I gave you on IRC ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git supports a number of different workflows.  See here for some conceptual diagrams to see some basic options: http://git-scm.com/about/distributed

To me, branches aren't typically related 1:1 with collaborators...that's what repositories themselves are for.  Branches are for keeping changes local to the task at hand.

Comment: & i think its good for politics as well , i'll put the master for my core team & branches for Contributors and if a branch works lets say 10x faster i can pull from it

Comment: Thanks guys. So it sounds like, in terms of local work, its a good idea to have a branch that contains only what goes into production and another for testing out ideas, etc. which I can then merge. It as simple as creating those branches and then when I don't want any recent changes to my project to be committed to the master branch, I just switch to the "testing" branch and commit/push from there? I'm just confused about the interaction between local project activity and git. If I add some code to my android project and save, those changes will have no effect on master repo unless I commit?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: I think terminology is clouding the issue a bit.  Typically "master" refers to a branch.  In a distributed VCS, not only can you save, you can also commit because you're only committing locally.  Then when things are stable you could push to your published repo (the one that others can see) at which point, depending on your workflow, it could be merged with the work of others.

Comment: Mark, thanks for responding. Sorry if I'm having trouble expressing this clearly. I'm trying to understand how you can control different branches have different versions. In other words, when I save (I just mean the code and nothing to do with git) changes to my project, but I want, say, Branch "B" to NOT have the newest changes, how do I do make that happen? It's by simply not committing in that branch, right?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: Yes, if you don't commit to git, it will not consider your changes to be part of the branch.  The typical workflow, however, would be to start a new branch in your private repo for your experimentation, but don't merge that branch into branch "B" (and don't push that branch).  One of the vital things that git brings to the table is internal version control: the ability to still have a history of revisions even if you never check in those changes such that anyone else can see them.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: Basically if you avoid using `git commit -a`, git will never commit any change that wasn't explicitly added by you.